# pandas groupby by the dictionary

Tags: pandas, dictionary, group-by

I encounter a problem:

```
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame({"code":['a','a','b','c','d'],
                'data':[3,4,3,6,7],})
mat={'group1':['a','b'],'group2':['a','c'],'group3':{'a','b','c','d'}}
```

the df like this

```
  code  data
0   a   3
1   a   4
2   b   3
3   c   6
4   d   7
```

I wanted the mean of the group1,group2,group3. In this example the key:group1 match the value:a,b , So I find the code equal a or b in df. the mean of group1 is (3+4+3)/3

```
group2 -> 'a','c' -> (3+4+6)/3
group3 -> 'a','b','c','d' ->(3+4+3+6+7)/5
```

I try to use groupby. It's doesn't works.
thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can do something like as follows:

```
In [133]: rules = {
     ...:   'grp1': ['a','b'],
     ...:   'grp2': ['a','c'],
     ...:   'grp3': list('abcd')
     ...: }
     ...:
     ...: r = pd.DataFrame(
     ...:     [{r:df.loc[df.code.isin(rules[r]), 'data'].mean()}
     ...:      for r in rules
     ...:     ]
     ...: ).stack()
     ...:

In [134]: r
Out[134]:
0  grp1    3.333333
1  grp2    4.333333
2  grp3    4.600000
dtype: float64
```